# How do I change UIPickerView text color in renderer view using Xamarin.Forms.iOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uipickerview

I have used UIPickerView in ios renderer file.I tried to change text and background color of view. Used  **SetValueForKeyPath** override method to change text color. While picker initially loaded into view text color was not changed but it does when  I change selected index(Problem with initial loading).

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomGrid> e)
{
   if (e.NewElement != null)
   {
      var nativeView = new UIPickerView();
      nativeView.Model = new PickerSource();
      nativeView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Yellow;
      nativeView.SetValueForKeyPath(UIColor.Red, (NSString)"textColor");
      CGRect cGRect = new CGRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
      SetNativeControl(nativeView);
   }

   base.OnElementChanged(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise against using a `PickerRenderer` to change the text color, because the `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PickerRenderer` is very complex; it's actually a `UIToolbar`, `UIBarButtonItem` and a `UITextField` combined into a `UIPickerView`.

[The code for `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PickerRenderer` is open-source](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/PickerRenderer.cs) if you'd like to see how the Xamarin.Forms team initialized a `Picker` on iOS.

#### Xamarin.Forms.Picker

It is much easier to set the `TextColor` in Xamarin.Forms:

```
var picker = new Xamarin.Forms.Picker
{
    TextColor = Color.Red
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but UIPickerView provides many functionalities that I need so I have used it for my entire project. Now I get this issue, Can you please suggest me a solution to overcome this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are doing with a Picker that requires a custom renderer? Check out the link to the Xamarin.Forms source code and emulate how they initialize a PickerRenderer on iOS.

Comment: I just used a Entry in Forms view, In renderer view I have used EditText, if editText got focus then picker popup will shown. My problem is while picker popup initially loading into view text color remains same. But it changes  after changing picker selected item.